# Why does dask read sql table sometimes slow down?

Tags: python, sql, performance, dask, fastapi

When inquiring data through FastAPI, sometimes the inquiry speed is more than doubled.

Here is part of the Dataframe inquiry code.

```py
    import dask.dataframe as dd
 
    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        username="aabcc",
        password="12345",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=2712,
        database="test",
        query={
            "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            "Trusted_Connection": "yes",
        },
    )

    def get_data():
        df = dd.read_sql_table(table='troya',
                           uri=connection_url, index_col='no')
        df = df.compute()
        
        return df
```

Here is part of the FastAPI part code.

```
    @bp.get("/test/{row}")
    def test_get(request: Request, row):
        df = get_data()
        ...
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me why this problem occurs.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It seems like you're asking about a very complex web application, but the code you posted only pertains to a limited subset of your question. Please see the guide on [ask] and provide all of the code, data, and context necessary for us to understand the problem, ideally as a [mre]. All of these are complex libraries, and diagnosing performance issues is not straightforward, so we can't just guess what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some data accumulates in `dd`?

Comment: @user17242583  Is there a way to initialize the dask.dataframe()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the core advantages of `dask` is the ability to distribute and coordinate workload across multiple workers. This advantage disappears when `dask` is used to load and immediately compute, so in the snippet above the following two lines are a bit of an antipattern:

```py
    df = dd.read_sql_table(table='troya',
                       uri=connection_url, index_col='no')
    df = df.compute()
```

What happens is work is distributed, but then has to be transferred from workers to a single client node. The solutions depend on your use case, if it's possible to continue the work in parallel/distributed fashion, then `dask` might still be handy, but if the workflow has to be sequential, then `pandas`/`sqlalchemy` might be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: thx 4 your answer!
but when i use pandas.read_sql_query(), it's run time is about 10s.
when change padnas.read_sql_query() to dask.dataframe.read_sql_table(), it's run time has decreased significantly.

Comment: `dd.read_sql_table` is lazy, it will return the delayed value almost instantly, so the more appropriate comparison is between pandas and the dask computed result...

Comment: see https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html for an overview of dask's lazy evaluation